# How to make a slush generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I have been trying to make a slush generator today with no luck.. I followed a couple of tutorials online and thought that I did everything right. However, when I run the generator it doesn't do anything.. I am not sure what I need to fix. Please let me know if you can spot my problem.. The files can be found here https://github.com/ryanswapp/slush-swappticon

slushfile.js

```
/*
 * slush-swappticon
 * https://github.com/ryanswapp/slush-swappticon
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2014, Ryan Swapp
 * Licensed under the MIT license.
 */

'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    install = require('gulp-install'),
    conflict = require('gulp-conflict'),
    template = require('gulp-template'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    _ = require('underscore.string'),
    inquirer = require('inquirer');

function format(string) {
    var username = string.toLowerCase();
    return username.replace(/\s/g, '');
}

var defaults = (function () {
    var homeDir = process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH || process.env.USERPROFILE,
        workingDirName = process.cwd().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop(),
        osUserName = homeDir && homeDir.split('/').pop() || 'root',
        configFile = homeDir + '/.gitconfig',
        user = {};
    if (require('fs').existsSync(configFile)) {
        user = require('iniparser').parseSync(configFile).user;
    }
    return {
        appName: workingDirName,
        userName: format(user.name) || osUserName,
        authorEmail: user.email || ''
    };
})();

gulp.task('default', function (done) {
    var prompts = [{
        name: 'appName',
        message: 'What is the name of your project?',
        default: defaults.appName
    }, {
        name: 'appDescription',
        message: 'What is the description?'
    }, {
        name: 'appVersion',
        message: 'What is the version of your project?',
        default: '0.1.0'
    }, {
        name: 'authorName',
        message: 'What is the author name?',
    }];
    //Ask
    inquirer.prompt(prompts,
        function (answers) {
            if (!answers.moveon) {
                return done();
            }
            answers.appNameSlug = _.slugify(answers.appName);
            gulp.src(__dirname + '/templates/**')
                .pipe(template(answers))
                .pipe(rename(function (file) {
                    if (file.basename[0] === '_') {
                        file.basename = '.' + file.basename.slice(1);
                    }
                }))
                .pipe(conflict('./'))
                .pipe(gulp.dest('./'))
                .pipe(install())
                .on('end', function () {
                    done();
                });
        });
});
```

package.json

```
{
    "name": "slush-swappticon",
    "description": "A simple AngularJS with ui-router generator",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "homepage": "https://github.com/ryanswapp/slush-swappticon",
    "author": {
        "name": "Ryan Swapp",
        "email": "ryancswapp@gmail.com"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git://github.com/ryanswapp/slush-swappticon.git"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/ryanswapp/slush-swappticon/issues"
    },
    "licenses": [{
        "type": "MIT",
        "url": "https://github.com/ryanswapp/slush-swappticon/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }],
    "main": "slushfile.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">= 0.10.26",
        "npm": ">=1.4.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"No tests\""
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "slush": ">=1.0.0",
        "gulp": "^3.6.2",
        "gulp-template": "^0.1.1",
        "gulp-install": "^0.1.4",
        "gulp-conflict": "^0.1.1",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
        "underscore.string": "^2.3.3",
        "inquirer": "^0.4.1",
        "iniparser": "^1.0.5"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "slushgenerator"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have `moveon` question but you are still checking it's answer.
Remove this part of code:

```
if (!answers.moveon) {
    return done();
}
```